# Xperia XZ Premium when set breakpoint application stop responding

Tags: android, adb, sony-xperia

I have connected my XZ Premium with Android Studio via adb and can set the breakpoint.
But if I set a breakpoint in Android Studio, the application can not be launched normally.It always stops responding.
Logcat shows
[image: please check the Logcat message]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable android instant run from settings.